# Run Javascript after XMLHttpRequest has been finished

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, xmlhttprequest

My Problem is that the JavaScript is faster than the XMLHttpRequest. I don't want to solve it with:

```
setTimeout(function() {}, 100);
```

My Code:

```
function change_country(id) {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

            document.getElementById("continent").value = data.continent;
            document.getElementById("country").value = data.country;

        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "request_country_change.php?id=" + id, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

The code is only an example, not the original. It should be a change form. So in this example it loads the list of all continents in the select field. And it select the continent which is related to the id and the same with the countries. But it only loads the list in the select fields but it runs the JavaScript part

```
document.getElementById("continent").value = data.continent;
document.getElementById("country").value = data.country;
```

to early. If I make between an alert or setTimeout it works, but can I solve it in another way?

Comment: What exactly does "too early" mean? How did you figure out it would work if ran later? What is the value of `xmlhttp.responseText` when the code runs, and what did you expect?

Comment: Please show the original code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The problem is in general, that a dynamically generated select list, at the same time has to choose an option which is stored in the database. It should be a change form. For example, I want to assign an article to another subcategorie.

Comment: You really should post your actual code. First, a working example with a static select list that does what need in the order you expect, then an incomplete example with the dynamic select list.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want its add to the select another js function like:

And in the js

```
function storeContinent(val){
     document.getElementById("continent").value = val;
}
```

Not sure if i get what you want